# Are questions about the field of physics off topic?

Tags: discussion

I often have questions about the field of physics itself (as opposed to physics questions). For example questions about the current state of a sub-field of physics, or questions about the implications of experiment results. The latter is especially important to me because my knowledge of physics is focused around classical electromagnetism, so I occasionally am confused about the significance of certain experiments. I am wondering if such questions are considered off-topic, or too opinion-driven to be asked here?

Comment: If you're uncertain ask in the chat room. Its liveliest period is from around 17:00 UTC, and if you ask then there'll be lots of people around to answer. The main site is best suited to well focussed questions, and it sounds as if you're more interested ina  discussion.

Comment: Note that some questions falling under this general category would be a good fit for [academia.se]. However, your question do not seem to be such ones.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft true! I am also active in that community so I have a general idea of what to ask/not ask over there.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say some, perhaps most, of these questions are physics questions, and thus I'd consider them on topic. Perhaps some other such questions are off topic. I couldn't say without having a better idea of what kinds of questions you're talking about.

Either way, I'd advise you to just ask them, and if they get closed, you'll learn something about what sorts of questions are considered off topic by the community.

Comment: Thanks I will try! I am trepidatious sometimes because I don't want to start an opinion war say, if I ask about the significance of experiment results. I also have some questions about the future of physics which would surely involve opinion but it shouldn't just be off-the-wall opinions.